# WordPress (3.5.1) Theme Media Upload gets frozen

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

I've read some of the topics here but did not found a solution for me. When I try to set a feature image to the post/portfolio the media upload window gets frozen(cant even close it down - pressing esc does the trick) and also can't set the feature image, upload an image, ..

If trying this in IE 8 I get a pop up error when opening the media upload(pressing set feature image) with this content "Out of memory at line 2!"

I am using the Wordpress version 3.5.1, thanks in advance for a posibble solution.

TNX!

May add that the IE8 also gives errors for: 
wp-admin/js/media-upload.min.js?ver=3.5.1 and 
wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js?ver=358-23224,
if switching to themeeleven the upload works ok, but not in my theme.

Answer (score 0):

If uploading works fine in a default Wordpress theme like twentyeleven or twentytwelve, that means there is a javascript conflict with your theme, esp. indicated by the IE8 errors. Possibly a plugin, but most likely the theme.

Look at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list?replies=4 to see if your theme (or a plugin) is listed as problematic and to learn how to check for javascript errors that will impact the Wordpress admin area.

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what javascript is loading on your site and see any errors and conflicts.